# Horizontal line too wide in vNiceArray

Tags: nicematrix

I'm using vNiceArray to typeset block determinants.

When you create a vNiceArray with the nicematrix package, a horizontal line is so long it reaches across the vertical lines, which does not look very good (it also makes the resulting determinant look more like a table than a determinant, which may be confusing). I'm not sure what would be the better solution, but I think the hline should not touch the vertical lines on the sides.

Can this be easily fixed? Or is there a better way to achieve the result?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{vNiceArray}{c|c}
            0&0\\
            \hline
            0&0
        \end{vNiceArray}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to mention, about your deleted post about diacritics with Xcharter and lualatex, that if you load `fontspec`, there is no problem.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, that is good to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add space on both sides with the key `margin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{vNiceArray}{c|c}[margin]
            0&0\\
            \hline
            0&0
    \end{vNiceArray}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want a `\hline` shorter, you can draw it with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{vNiceArray}{c|c}
            0&0\\
            0&0
    \CodeAfter
      \tikz \draw [shorten > = 0.5em, shorten < = 0.5em](2-|1) -- (2-|last) ;
    \end{vNiceArray}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output the second code]

You can also create your own command `\MyHline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \MyHline { }
  { 
    \noalign 
      { 
        \skip_vertical:N \arrayrulewidth 
        \tl_gset:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
          { \__tomasz_MyHline:n { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { c@iRow } + 1 } } } 
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tomasz_MyHline:n
  { \tikz \draw [shorten~> = 0.5em, shorten~< = 0.5em](#1-|1) -- (#1-|last) ; }
\ExplSyntaxOff
  
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{vNiceArray}{c|c}
            0&0\\ \MyHline 
            0&0
    \end{vNiceArray}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]